# Django MySQL Backup in sql file format

Tags: python, mysql, django, backup

I have project in Django and Database in MySQL and I want Backup of DB every week so that If anything goes wrong with server or database so I can use that DB, but unfortunalty I didn't find any solution that can help me.

I'm trying to get backup of database every week, I have MySQL database and I have also tried using 'django-dbbackup' but it's not giveing output as expected in '.sql' format.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to backup your database is to use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html). This is a tool completely independant of Django. It produces a file with all your database, tables and data, in SQL format. It is very popular and you can find many ways to use it on the internet.

You can use it directly with a scheduled task on your server for example (with [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on Linux)

You can also integrates it in Django with a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) (for using it on the server). You may also run it inside a view in order to trigger it from your browser.

Like every external program, you can use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run it from Django.

Finally, i would advice to use [mysqlcheck](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) after mysqldump for optimizing the database regularly.

Comment: Please, if my answer helped you, can you consider marking it as accepted ? Thank you